# How to use loop in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

My $array has 32 values and I want to use loop but I don't have idea.

```
if ( $array[0]  > 1)
{
    echo $array[0];
    unset($array[0]);
}

else if ( $array[1]  > 1)
{
    echo $array[1];
    unset($array[1]);
}

else if ( $array[2]  > 1)
{
    echo $array[2];
    unset($array[2]);
}
else
{
    echo  "<a href=' ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$daystring."&year=".$year." '>".$i." </a></td>";
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php), [for](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) or [while](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php) to iterate over the array.

Comment: I can see there is a $i variable, from that it looks like you already have tried looping?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-foreach-actually-work

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this

```
foreach($array as $index => $value)
{
    if ($value > 1)
    {
        echo $value;
        unset($array[$index]);
    }
    else
    {
        echo  '<a href="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?month=', $monthstring, '&day=', $daystring, '&year=', $year, '>', $index, '</a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with that else? At which point you would like to stop loop? Might be I missed a point. You might go with Barmar's solution but you can avoid that $deleted variable and brake right after echo in else brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Else is after whole loop, I think it should be like this:

```
$found = false;
foreach($array as $index => $value)
{
    if ($value > 1)
    {
        echo $value;
        unset($array[$index]);
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(!$found) { 
    echo  '<a href="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?month=', $monthstring, '&day=', $daystring, '&year=', $year, '>', $index, '</a>';
}
```

Comment: The original code only echoes and unsets the first value that's found, not all of them. That's why my answer breaks out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `foreach` loop, and break out of it after unsetting the first element greater than 1. Use a variable to track whether anything was deleted, so you know whether to echo the anchor after the loop.

```
$deleted = false;
foreach ($array as $index => $value) {
    if ($value > 1) {
        echo $value;
        unset($array[$value]);
        $deleted = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$deleted) {
    echo  "<a href=' ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?month=".$monthstring."&day=".$daystring."&year=".$year." '>".$i." </a></td>";
}
```